# Is it possible to restore files from a Borg / Vorta backup repository from another machine?

Tags: backup, borgbackup

I have used an external disk to backup a laptop, for several months, using Borg-Vorta, under Linux Mint 21.3.

The laptop has had a major failure, and is no more accessible.

Now I have a new laptop, on which I have installed the same system, I have created the same user, and I have installed Borg-Vorta.

Is there a way to access the old backups, from the external disk?

I haven't done any backup of cryptographic keys from the first machine, and on that machine I used the default configuration (i.e. using the ssh key).

--

Since I have the feeling the answer is simply "no", could you please explain me how to not end up in this situation again?
Can you explain how to "export" the crypto keys, so to access the same backup repository on a different machine?